# How to find the number of strings with even and odd number of zeroes?

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

Any hints please for this question ? Im stuck.How to find the number of strings with even and odd number of zeroes ?

Comment: But still i prefer substituting values of $n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Here is how you count the number of strings with $k$ zeroes:

There are $\binom{n}{k}$ possible positions for the zeroes. For each of the remaining $n-k$ positions you have 3 choices of digits.

So the number of strings with exactly $k$ zeroes is 
$$
\binom{n}{k}3^{n-k}
$$

**Hint 2**
Prove that 
$$
E_n-O_n =(3+(-1))^n \\
E_n+O_n=(3+1)^n
$$

Answer (score 2):

How many total strings of length $n$ are there? Are there any strings with neither an even nor an odd number of zeros?

Comment: I'm not sure if you made the connection, so just for completeness: there are $4^n$ strings in total, and *every* string either has an odd number of zeros or an even number of zeros. Therefore, the total strings with *either* an odd or even number of zeros must be *all* the strings, therefore choice $A$ is correct.

Comment: @SSS and why is (D) wrong?

Comment: What about the other options?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of hints.

- What is the total number of $n$-digit strings that can be constructed with the digits $0,1,2,3$?
- If a string doesn't have an odd number of zeroes in it, what must be true about that string?  (Answer: It must have an ____ number of zeroes in it.)
- Given a number of disjoint subsets that cover all of the elements in the superset, you can add up the elements in each subset to get the total in the superset.

Comment: Can you answer the second question please.That's exactly where i'm stuck...

Comment: What's the opposite of *odd*?

Comment: Are you joking or something.Even.So? How to find the number of strings having even digits?

Comment: No, I'm not joking; I'm trying to lead you to the answer.  :)

Comment: Well :-P!I still cant get number of strings having even digits

Comment: And btw can we show number of strings having even number is equal to number of strings having odd numbers of 0

Comment: What's the total number of strings, with any number of zeroes?  (Answer to my first question)

Comment: 4^n right ???? @John

Comment: Yep.  And if you know that the number of strings with an even number of zeroes is $E_n$, and the number of strings with an odd number of zeroes is $O_n$, what can you then say?

Comment: Well option (A) is correct.But i want to calculate On and En

Comment: Oh ok ... that's a separate question, though.  It looked like you were asking for the answer to the multiple-choice question (which is indeed $A$).

Comment: No (A),(B),(C) are correct.It has more than one correct options.

Comment: Ahhh ... my apologies.  Incorrect assumption on my part.

Answer (score 0):

See for even total ways where we can fit $0$ is ${2n\choose 0}+{2n\choose 2}+...+{2n\choose 2n}=4^n/2$ same logic goes for odd numbers thus options correct are $A$

Comment: $D$ is false. For instance, $E_1=3$ but $O_1 = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the a given $n$ whole universe of the strings is the sum of $E_n+O_n$, which is $4^n$.

MECE: Mutually exclusive, collectively exhaustive.